# Disable or uninstall side bar on android

Tags: uninstallation

I'm wondering if it is possible to disable or uninstall this bar that I show on this image. I'm sorry i don't know what it is named that is why I included the image (click to enlarge). I'm using Android version 4.1.

[image: side bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://sophiemr.blogspot.in/2012/12/samsung-galaxy-s3-41-update-feature_27.html) specified how to disable this Multi window feature in Samsung 4.1 Jellybean's feature.

You can disable it by clicking Multi-window Icon on Notification bar.

Comment: Answer with only a link isn't considered helpful.

Comment: Thats why I added the second line. :)
It's the method to disable Multi window.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize. Cheers.

Comment: No problms. cheers :)